# jsTree + jsTreeGrid -> render icons for newly created node

Tags: jstree

I successfully implements jsTree + jsTreeGrid in admin panel for
managing categories for products.
The only one problem is, that when i create new node via right mouse button context menu, the newly
created row does not contain columns with icons set in jsTreeGrid panel. The icons
are ID based (linked to other pages), therefore while rendering icons code have to know ID of newly created node.

Please note: After page refresh icons for new node are visible. Of course.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about programmatically refreshing the jsTree after adding new node? Search for `refresh` in [doc for core](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core)

Comment: Thank you for your point Radek, it may temporarily help to solve the problem, even it is not elegant solution. I would rather force jsTree to render columns content directly without any kind of refresh.

Comment: Not sure it this is `possible`. You can ask the author of jsTreeGrid https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid